# PHP code to accept Monero payments from mainet website

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I don't fully understand how to create a payment method for a website built using php and mysql. I mean without using Globee which has a minimin of $10.

My website will be for listings with small amounts payable to list. I want to give customers the ability to pay in Monero, the equivalent of the $2 or $5 or as the payment button says. I will run my node, with Monero GUI from a Win 10 computer, with maybe a Trezor or Nano to serve as hard wallet.

I understand that users have to scan a code, and press send. Is there not an easier way to accept payments direct to wallet for listings?

Can someone provide an example code, say if you want to create a button for $2, when the user chooses to pay, he clicks the $2 button, and this amount is automatically converted to Monero and he pays and the monero reaches my wallet.

Where can I see code which gives such examples?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no easy way around this. You will have to dive into the documentation, and code yourself. https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html

Comment: This is incredibly broad for a SE question. - 

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.